# Keycloak v20.0.3 - I can't connect to Postgresql 12 via IP:Port

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

As title, I am unable to connect to Postgresql 12 on VM but for Postgresql deployed on K8S it connects normally.

Here is my info:

- Docker Desktop 4.16.3 (96739)
- Keycloak v20.0.3 (v20.0.1 also got the same error)
- VM: Postgresql 12 - Ubuntu 18.04

My env:

- KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
- KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
- KC_DB=postgres
- KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=web-oidc-v20
- KC_DB_URL_HOST=192.168.201.23
- KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432
- KC_DB_USERNAME=web-oidc
- KC_DB_PASSWORD=Abcd@1234
- KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=http://localhost:8080
- KC_HOSTNAME_URL=http://localhost:8080

(I also tried to use `KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.201.23:5432/web-oidc-v20` as replacement for `KC_DB_URL_DATABASE, KC_DB_URL_HOST, KC_DB_URL_PORT` but it didn't work either)

Here is the docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e KC_DB=postgres -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=web-oidc-v20 -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=192.168.201.23 -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 -e KC_DB_USERNAME=web-oidc -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=Abcd@1234 -e KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=http://localhost:8080 -e KC_HOSTNAME_URL=http://localhost:8080 web-oidc-v20
```

Container logs:

```
Changes detected in configuration. Updating the server image.
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2023-02-08 08:55:41,942 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-26) KC-SERVICES0047: load-digo-user (vn.vnpt.digo.iscs.keycloak.spi.authenticator.LoadDigoUserAuthenticatorFactory) is implementing the internal SPI authenticator. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
2023-02-08 08:55:46,242 WARN  [io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ReflectiveHierarchyStep] (build-104) Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
        - javax.servlet.http.Cookie (source: JacksonProcessor > org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest$Builder)
Consider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.
2023-02-08 08:55:53,256 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 14734ms
Server configuration updated and persisted. Run the following command to review the configuration:

        kc.sh show-config

Next time you run the server, just run:

        kc.sh start --optimized

2023-02-08 08:55:55,649 INFO  [vn.vnpt.digo.iscs.keycloak.spi.authenticator.LoadDigoUserAuthenticatorFactory] (main) init
2023-02-08 08:55:55,751 INFO  [vn.vnpt.digo.iscs.keycloak.spi.user.storage.DigoUserStorageProviderFactory] (main) init
2023-02-08 08:55:55,753 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: http://localhost:8080, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: /, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: http://localhost:8080, Admin: localhost, Port: 8080, Proxied: false
2023-02-08 08:55:58,207 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2023-02-08 08:55:59,484 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-02-08 08:55:59,546 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2023-02-08 08:55:59,608 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2023-02-08 08:56:00,138 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2023-02-08 08:56:00,135 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
2023-02-08 08:56:00,195 WARN  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.database.LegacyJpaConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Unable to prepare operational info due database exception: Connection has been closed.
2023-02-08 08:56:00,428 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `ISPN`
2023-02-08 08:56:00,429 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000088: Unable to use any JGroups configuration mechanisms provided in properties {}. Using default JGroups configuration!
2023-02-08 08:56:00,585 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (main) Datasource '<default>': Connection has been closed.
2023-02-08 08:56:00,613 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
2023-02-08 08:56:00,618 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 20.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
2023-02-08 08:56:00,620 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
2023-02-08 08:56:00,622 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 25.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
2023-02-08 08:56:02,644 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) 87e253982a2b-10337: no members discovered after 2001 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
2023-02-08 08:56:02,662 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [87e253982a2b-10337|0] (1) [87e253982a2b-10337]
2023-02-08 08:56:02,668 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000079: Channel `ISPN` local address is `87e253982a2b-10337`, physical addresses are `[192.168.0.2:33278]`
2023-02-08 08:56:03,341 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ISPN`
2023-02-08 08:56:03,507 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
2023-02-08 08:56:03,508 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to validate database
2023-02-08 08:56:03,508 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
2023-02-08 08:56:03,508 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Connection has been closed.
2023-02-08 08:56:03,509 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

Postgresql Logs:

```
2023-02-08 14:59:19.553 +07 [2652184] web-oidc@web-oidc-v20 LOG:  connection authorized: user=web-oidc database=web-oidc-v20 SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256, compression=off)
2023-02-08 14:59:20.758 +07 [2652184] web-oidc@web-oidc-v20 FATAL:  relation "migration_model" does not exist at character 25
2023-02-08 14:59:20.758 +07 [2652184] web-oidc@web-oidc-v20 STATEMENT:  SELECT ID, VERSION FROM MIGRATION_MODEL ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC
2023-02-08 14:59:20.758 +07 [2652184] web-oidc@web-oidc-v20 LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:01.577 user=web-oidc database=web-oidc-v20 host=192.168.200.25 port=62448
```

Please let me know where I am wrong, sincerely thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I was having. It was because 1 value in Postgresql config was blocking my connection!
`exit_on_error`

Answer (score 0):

try to replace localhost in your docker command with host.docker.internal.

Docker cannot resolve localhost.
So, you need to run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e KC_DB=postgres -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=web-oidc-v20 -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=192.168.201.23 -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 -e KC_DB_USERNAME=web-oidc -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=Abcd@1234 -e KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8080 -e KC_HOSTNAME_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8080 web-oidc-v20
```

Also, not sure about this

```
-e KC_DB_URL_HOST=192.168.201.23
```

Also, I see you are trying to start it in production mode. Is it expected? If no then add in the end start-dev.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your method but the above error still occurs. Looks like the problem is in Postgres `ERROR: Failed to validate database`?

Comment: @CNStudios try this docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e KC_DB=postgres -e KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgres://host.docker.internal:5432/web-oidc-v20 -e KC_DB_USERNAME=web-oidc -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=Abcd@1234 -e KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8080 -e KC_HOSTNAME_URL=http://host.docker.internal web-oidc-v20

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the problem I was having. It was because 1 value in Postgresql config was blocking my connection!